# Count records based on there status laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to count records in a table based on there Status

```
+--------|-----------|-------------+
|  id    |  Record   |   Status    |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|   1    | 20        |    A        |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|   2    | 10        |    A        |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|   3    | 15        |    D        |
+----------------------------------+
```

The problem is im using a SUM query as well as a Count query.

```
->select(DB::raw('SUM(Record) as commission, COUNT(Status) as status'))
->get()
```

Now this works, but not based on Statust Results. I have tried the following at it does not work.

```
->select(DB::raw('SUM(Record) as commission, COUNT(Status = A) as status'))
->get()
```

AND

```
->select(DB::raw('SUM(Record) as commission, COUNT(Status) as status WHERE Status = "A" '))
->get()
```

AND

```
->select(DB::raw('SUM(Record) as commission, COUNT(Status = "A ") as status'))
->get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change -

```
COUNT(STATUS = 'A')
```

To:

```
SUM(Status = 'A')
```

Boolean expression returns `0/1` based on the condition. `COUNT(0)` will still count 1, only `COUNT(NULL)` doesn't add 1 to the counter. `SUM()` in the other hand, will sum 1 when the condition is true, and 0 when it false.

Comment: Ooo...Omg Thank you so much.. You Saved My Life...@sagi

Comment: Saved my life too :)